# Using AFNetworking to POST a file asynchronously with upload progress to Strava V3 API

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I would like to post an activity to Strava from iOS.

Strava docs (http://strava.github.io/api/v3/uploads/#post-file) have curl example as following:

EXAMPLE REQUEST

```
$ curl -X POST https://www.strava.com/api/v3/uploads \
    -F access_token=83ebeabdec09f6670863766f792ead24d61fe3f9 \
    -F activity_type=ride \
    -F file=@test.fit \
    -F data_type=fit
```

In this case the file test.fit is the activity to post.

I am attempting to post this asynchronously using AFNetworking. I have the following test code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.strava.com"];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];

AFOAuthCredential *credential = [AFOAuthCredential retrieveCredentialWithIdentifier:kStravaTokenStored];

NSString *accessToken = credential.accessToken;

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"access_token": accessToken, @"activity_type" : @"ride",@"data_type" : @"fit", @"name" : @"Test", @"stationary" : @"1" };

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/api/v3/uploads" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
[formData appendPartWithFileData:fileData name:@"Test" fileName:@"Test.fit" mimeType:@"application/octet-stream"];
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"succss %@", responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"failure %@ \n\n %@", error, operation);

}];

[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

Currently I am seeing the following error:

> Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code
>   in (200-299), got 400" UserInfo=0x9b62300
>   {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion={"message":"Bad
>   Request","errors":[{"resource":"Upload","field":"data","code":"empty"}]},

Anyone have an idea what I am missing here?

Thanks Ants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be

```
[formData appendPartWithFileData:fileData name:@"file" fileName:@"Test.fit" mimeType:@"application/octet-stream"]
```

or not?

Comment: You were right. Thanks for this. I just needed to change the name to file. Didn't even see that. Thanks!