# Uploading GPX file to Strava API with GTMHTTPFetcher POST in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, post, xmlhttprequest

After exploring the use of the Strava API (http://strava.github.io/api/v3) with GTMHTTPFetcher for 2 days I am now completely stuck at uploading a .gpx file to my account so I made the decision to ask for an answer here. I successfully received and stored an access token with the necessary 'view_private,write' permission and the server is responding to requests and I managed to receive and change data stored in my account. When trying to upload a .gpx (xml) file I get an error (bad request):

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)

There is something I don't understand about constructing a HTTP POST request apparently and I tried different approaches experimenting with the values in the http header, changed the fetch url after '/uploads?' with file=... etc. to no avail. For authentication I use GTMOAuth2Authentication.

My code:

```
- (void) uploadToStrava {

    NSString *filePath = @"somefilepath.gpx";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.strava.com/api/v3/uploads?data_type=gpx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];

    [self.signedStravaAuth authorizeRequest:request];

    GTMHTTPFetcher* myStravaFetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher fetcherWithRequest:request];
    [myStravaFetcher beginFetchWithDelegate:self
                          didFinishSelector:@selector(myStravaFetcher:finishedWithData:error:)];
    self.currentFetcher = myStravaFetcher;

}

- (void) myStravaFetcher:(GTMHTTPFetcher *)fetcher finishedWithData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError *) error {
    if (error != nil) {
        [self handleErrorWithText:nil];
        NSLog(@"error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        NSString *info = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *result = [self.jsonParser objectWithString:info];
        NSLog(@"Strava response: %@", result);
    }
}
```

The API docs come with the following example request in CURL:

```
$ curl -X POST https://www.strava.com/api/v3/uploads \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer 83ebeabdec09f6670863766f792ead24d61fe3f9" \
    -F activity_type=ride \
    -F file=@test.fit \
    -F data_type=fit
```

Related question: [Using AFNetworking to POST a file asynchronously with upload progress to Strava V3 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305707/using-afnetworking-to-post-a-file-asynchronously-with-upload-progress-to-strava)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I turned out formatting the body myself and I learned about how to accomplish this with the help of the example in the following link: http://nthn.me/posts/2012/objc-multipart-forms.html. I experienced troubles with the last boundary though because it needed an extra `--` afterwards which was missing in the example. Luckily I found out about this quickly because I was reading up about the multipart HTTP POST protocol here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.strava.com/api/v3/uploads"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"YOUR_BOUNDARY_STRING";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", usefullFileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data_type\"\r\n\r\n%@", @"gpx"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"\r\n\r\n%@", @"Some Name"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:body encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", strData); // human readable body in log

    [self.signedStravaAuth authorizeRequest:request];

    GTMHTTPFetcher* myStravaFetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher fetcherWithRequest:request];
    [myStravaFetcher beginFetchWithDelegate:self
                         didFinishSelector:@selector(myStravaFetcher:finishedWithData:error:)];
```

Now the server responds with "Your activity is still being processed." and I see the map arrived in my account on Strava.

I'm sure GTMHTTPFetcher is able to provide with an easier to read/handle solution but I haven't found it yet and this solution is satisfying.

Comment: This could be part of much cleaner solution for GTMHTTPFetcher:

https://code.google.com/p/gtm-http-fetcher/wiki/MultipartPost

Comment: Can you tell me the class of this object "signedStravaAuth" ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are receiving an HTTP 400 it means the Strava V3 API is rejecting your request - generally 400s from the uploads endpoint include information in the response about what is wrong. I would start by examining the response body for your error response. I'm not familiar with GTMHTTPFetcher, but you should either be able to debug and observe the response body or you can use a tool like [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com) to debug the request and response. Try comparing a `curl` request and the request coming from your Objective-C code.

The Strava V3 Uploads API expects the file portion of the upload to be in a `file` parameter - again, without being familiar with GTMHTTPFetcher I can't say for sure what it is doing, but it doesn't seem like you are specifying that the file data be part of a `multipart/form-data` section called `file`.

A long-shot: it also seems like you are mixing POST body and query string parameters, so your `data_type` parameter *might* not be making it through. I'd be consistent and put all the params in the POST body.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pushing me in the right direction. I now am able to answer my question myself.

Comment: No problem! FWIW we use AFNetworking extensively and have found it very easy to do a variety of kinds of requests (different content types, multipart, etc…) - I'd recommend giving AFNetworking a try.

Comment: I'll give it a try in the future. I guess it will handle authentication as well? I started using GTMHTTPFetcher because was experimenting with communicating with the Vimeo API first and this was the fetching library that was used in an example I found.